# MySQL duplicate join on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got a table of postcodes:

```
id INT, postcode VARCHAR(8)
```

and a table of distances between those postcodes that only stores the distance in ONE DIRECTION between two different postcodes, so from postcode ID 2 to postcode ID 5 the distance is only ever stored either as `2, 5, 78.2` or as `5, 2, 78.2` but not both.

```
from INT, to INT, dist DECIMAL
```

The primary key on the distances is (from, to) and I have an index on each of the columns in that table too.

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM listings, postcode_distances,
     postcodes postcode_listings, postcodes postcode_searchterm
WHERE listing.`status` = 3
AND listings.category = 8
AND postcode_listings.id = listings.postcode_id
AND (
     (postcode_distances.to = postcode_listings.id AND
      postcode_distances.from = postcode_searchterm.id AND
      postcode_distances.dist < 30)
     OR
     (postcode_distances.from = postcode_listings.id AND
      postcode_distances.to = postcode_searchterm.id AND
      postcode_distances.dist < 30)
)
AND postcode_searchterm.postcode = 'AB11'
GROUP BY id_listings
ORDER BY postcode_distances.dist ASC;
```

The query runs slowly (as you probably expect) and locks up the database as a side-effect.

EXPLAINing the query shows this row for the postcode_distances join:

```
1 | SIMPLE | postcode_distances | ALL | PRIMARY,dist,to,from | 695332 | Using where; Using join buffer
```

Is there any way I can achieve the two joins (where the postcode that is searched for is EITHER the `from` or the `to` column) in a single query?

I can use a UNION and just run the query twice, but put each half of the postcode_distance OR condition in each of the query's but I wanted to check whether I'd missed another, simpler, way of doing this?

Comment: you should consider using JOIN syntax and not commas between your tables.

Comment: @thanks bluefeet I'm aware that I'm not using the right syntax and that my column names are reserved words

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT postcodes.id       AS SearchedId, 
       postcodes.postcode AS SearchedPostCode, 
       p1.postcode        AS FromPostCode, 
       p2.postcode        AS ToPostCode, 
       p1.id              AS FromPostCodeId, 
       p2.id              AS ToPostCodeId, 
       postcode_distances.dist 
FROM   listings 
       INNER JOIN postcodes 
         ON postcodes.id = listings.postcode_id 
       INNER JOIN postcode_distances 
         ON ( postcode_distances.to1 = postcodes.id 
               OR postcode_distances.from1 = postcodes.id ) 
       INNER JOIN postcodes p1 
         ON postcode_distances.From1 = p1.id 
       INNER JOIN postcodes p2 
         ON postcode_distances.to1 = p2.id 
WHERE  listings.status = 3 
       AND listings.category = 8 
       AND postcode_distances.dist < 30 
       AND postcodes.postcode = 'AB11' 
ORDER  BY postcode_distances.dist ASC;
```

[Refer Sql Fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d7f2/11)

Comment: This would restrict the results to only show listings with a postcode of AB11... I need to show listings within 30 miles of the postcode AB11

Comment: @Jon, did you tried the query on your database. It will show all the postcode for AB11 which are under 30 miles

Comment: yes it doesn't work. Your JOINs here restrict the `listings` to only those with a postcode_id that equals that of 'AB11'

Comment: @Jon, you can see the image attached in the post. It has listed down all data of three tables and the result of query. If you expect other result then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for that - hadn't come across sqlfiddle before! If you can get your query to list the postcodes that match postcode ID 3, 6 and 4 from this set of results then you've done it! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d7f2/1 (notice how 3 is in the TO column and 6 and 4 are in the FROM column)

Comment: @Jon, can we go for chatting to discuss this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11645/discussion-between-romil-and-jon)

Comment: refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d7f2/11 for desired solution and check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this comment if you find something wrong

```
 select * from listings, postcode_distances pDis,postcodes post
 WHERE listing.status = 3 AND listings.category = 8
 AND (pDis.to = post.id OR pDis.from = post.id) AND post.postcode = 'AB11' 
 AND pDis.dist < 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     listings
  JOIN   postcodes postcode_listings ON postcode_listings.id = listings.postcode_id
  JOIN   postcodes postcode_searchterm
  JOIN   postcode_distances
    ON ( (listings.postcode_id, postcode_searchterm.id)
         IN (
           (postcode_distances.to,   postcode_distances.from),
           (postcode_distances.from, postcode_distances.to)
         )
     AND postcode_distances.dist < 30
    )
WHERE    listings.status = 3
     AND listings.category = 8
     AND postcode_searchterm.postcode = 'AB11'
GROUP BY id_listings
ORDER BY postcode_distances.dist ASC;
```

Comment: Nearly... but `postcode_distances.from = listings.postcode_id` also needs to be in there because if the postcode_searchterm matches the `to` column in postcode_distances, then I want results from listing which match the id in `from`

Comment: @Jon: Ah, I'd misread the query in your question.  See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE p.id WHEN d.`from` THEN p.postcode END) AS from_postcode,
  MAX(CASE p.id WHEN d.`to`   THEN p.postcode END) AS to_postcode,
  d.`from`,
  d.`to`,
  d.`dist`,
  MAX(l.id_listings) AS id_listings
FROM postcode_distances d
INNER JOIN postcodes p ON p.id IN (d.`from`, d.`to`)
LEFT JOIN listings l ON l.postcode_id = p.id AND l.`status` = 3 AND l.category = 8
WHERE p.postcode =  'AB11' AND l.id_listings IS     NULL
   OR p.postcode <> 'AB11' AND l.id_listings IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  d.`from`,
  d.`to`,
  d.`dist`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The query uses an outer join to a specific subset of `listings` and retrieves rows that either have a match in that subset or have a specific `postcode`. The rows are then grouped and the groups are ensured to have exactly two rows.